# How to pass data between two react sibling components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components:  which takes value from an input field. Second component is  which I fetch api data. The problem is that I want to get the value from GetSearch as the value i search the API in Pexels.

I have tried to change my code multiple times. I just cant understand how it is supposed to be done, and how should I actually communicate together with my components.

```
import React from "react";

class GetSearch extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {value: ''};

          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
          this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        handleChange(event) {
          this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        }

        handleSubmit(event) {
          alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
          event.preventDefault();
        }

        render() {
          var PassValue = React.CreateClass({
            render: function() {
              return (
                <p>{this.state.value}</p>
              );
            },
          });

          return (
            <form className="search-form">
            <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Search for images" 
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
          );
        }
      }

export default GetSearch
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Pexels extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        let query = "water"
        const url = `https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${query}e+query&per_page=15&page=1`
        const api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
          headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': api_key
          })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello</h1>)
    }
}
```

So as you can see now: Pexels sends a get request with the value of water: let query = "water", which works fine. But I need the value from
this.state.value in the GetSearch component

Comment: time for [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a parent class. Then You need to pass callback functions to the children as props. Here GetSearch component can be your child class. After you click search button your main class method will notify that change. Then create your logic as you want. 
Follow this example code. thanks

**Parent Component**

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
        update: function() {
            console.log("updated!");
        },
        render: function() {
          <ChildComponent callBack={this.update} />
        }
    })
```

**Child Component**

```
    var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    preupdate: function() {
        console.log("pre update done!");
    },
    render: function() {
      <button onClick={this.props.callback}>click to update parent</button>
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need a store(just a function) to fetch url data rather than in a UI component `Pexels`.

In `GetSearch` invoke the store function with input as parameter and return a promise, and get data in callback.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about Redux - which is certainly an option (but not needed just to share state between 2 sibling components). But this "answer" is not sufficiently detailed for anyone who doesn't already know about Redux to understand how to implement this.

Comment: Of course not, It just the part of MVC, you don't need to know redux.